# Warning to run php on terminal "Unable to load dynamic library"

Tags: php

I have fresh install `Ubuntu 16.04` and then install `php`. But its not looks good. I got following warning to run php. I try lots answer about it but nothing helps me.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

PHP installation Path `/etc/php/5.6`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` yet?

Comment: Yes!! Almost all try related this..